# Mystery scroll wheel input only during certain time of day

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling

I'm running windows 7 and starting a few weeks ago, around 5:30ish my scroll wheel (wired mouse) behaves erratically.  Symptoms include

- When I scroll up it scrolls down
- When I scroll nothing happens
- Doing nothing causes fast scroll jumps all over
- Sometimes it works

It lasts about an hour or so.  I've not been able to track it down, and I can't see any scheduled tasks that start at 5pm.  I installed USBlyzer to try to capture HID input in case it was being generated elsewhere, but the program doesn't seem to capture anything (else I've not figured out how to use it properly).

Not sure how to track this one down.  Performed quick-n-dirty malware check, nothing bad found.  Currently running more thorough test.

*MORE INFO*

I have 2 monitors, and it seems to affect which monitor the window is on.  On one screen, I'll have problems, but when I move the window to the other monitor, the problem goes away.  Move it back, and problem returns.

Though I do experience the problem on the other monitor, just much less frequently.

Comment: It was acting up again starting at about 5:25pm, so I rebooted the computer, still acting up. I killed off most all of the process, but that didn't fix it.  I then went to services and it can be a coincidence, but when I turned off 'AMD External Events Utility', it stopped.  Could have been coincidence as it does stop by itself after some time.  Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: that didn't help.  shut down some more services, and it happened again today.  this is crazy.

Comment: A mouse developing its own volition is usually a hardware problem. To verify, you might try another mouse.

Comment: Since the problem disappears on second monitor, seems like a software issue. Still to get the doubts cleared,
1. Try this mouse with different system
2. Try using a different mouse during "Ghost hours' :P

Comment: It might be worth having a look in your Windows Update history (via the Windows Update icon in control panel) and see if anything was installed about 2 weeks ago when it started.  I'd be looking at display driver related things.  (Also, I'd be checking to see if any of my colleagues were sniggering while it was playing up, just saying).

Comment: I can't imagine the mouse itself going crazy at a particular time and dependant on which window the mouse is in.  The only thing that got installed was the synergy server at around the time the problem started (it lets you control the mouse/keyboard) but the server lets you control a different computer.  killed process and service but it still went crazy.   Also, I work by myself, no colleagues, but good guess.

Comment: have you tried other mouse?

Comment: @reza This is a long shot, but I used to have a very similar problem to this. Are you using a USB display adapter for either of your monitors? I used to use an HP DisplayLink Adapter and while certain things were running it would make scrolling in programs and browsers on that screen nearly impossible.

Comment: no display adapter.

Comment: Just two suggestions: 1) unplug the network cable at the moment the problem occurs and see if it helps. 2) Set you time to 5:15pm during the day and see if it occurs. (you might need to disable the automatic time-sync if it doesn't stick.) If the problem occurs at 5:30(ish) according to the clock it is definitively a task that's run at that time. You might want to disable the task scheduler for a while, there are a lot of hidden tasks there. Or display running tasks at that time - `action, display all running tasks`. Also `enable all task history` to check for that time after it happened.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try to break it down to a soft or hardwareproblem:

## Software

**Before it starts:**

- Check again if you really haven't installed any software, which triggers something at this time?(batch-script etc.)
- Check possible bad services at `msconfig.exe`(which will start at startup for example)
- Check your video drivers if they are actual or not.
- Check if you really haven't installed new software/updates since this strange behavior. (maybe automatic updates)
- Check if the driver is actual and update them, if needed.
- Check, if there is another mouse-driver-software installed.
- Use a System Restore-Point to restore to a point, before it started and check, if it still happens. **If it still happens**, it **must** be hardware problem.

**During the strange movement:**

- Check the processes by opening a `cmd` and execute a `tasklist`-command to check, which processes are running, make a screenshot/safe the list to a file and when the strange behavior stops, check if there are processes which only run, during the mouse goes strange.
- Sniff The mouse input with [USBTrace](http://www.sysnucleus.com)

## Hardware

**Before it starts:**

- Use another mouse. Even if you think, that it's not possible, you should do it to be sure.

  - Maybe there is a bad-contact in the mouse.
- Check the mouse, if there is dust in it.

**During the strange movement**

- Remove the mouse to check, if the inputs still happen.

## My idea

So, now my idea. You said, that it happens, when you go to the second screen. So you have to move the mouse a "long" way. So maybe There is **bad contact** in the mouse, which will be triggered, if you move the mouse a long way. So if you move the mouse back, it will stop, because the bad contact will stop.

Yes, it's a strange idea, but it's also a strange problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried killing off as many processes as possible and stopping services but nothing seems to be the culprit.  And the clockwork nature of it starting and lasting for about 45minutes-hour exactly around 5:33(ish) makes me rule out a hardware issue.  I've upgraded the vid driver, etc.  I'm sure it's some stupid software bug.  Wish there was a way to monitor mouse input to help see if there is a pattern.  I looked into tracking USB HID data but the usb sniffers didn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Use [USBTrace](http://www.sysnucleus.com) as sniffer.

Answer (score 1):

How about unplugging the mouse when this thing starts and see if it persists.
This way you could at least rule-out the physical aspect.

(btw, I know it's a long shot, could there be an extreme temperature change that somehow affects the surface or the mouse itself?)